# Dynamic variable names EL

Tags: jsp, el

I'm writing a Mortgage Calculator and the user should be able to input a range of interest rates, and the program will return a table displaying all the monthly payments between those two rates.

I'm using EL to pass the variables from my controller to the results page. I have named all the interest rate variables rate0,rate1,rate2, ect. but I can't figure out how to pick them up in a loop in EL. I've tried a few different things. Originally I was hoping to just be able to say something along the lines of `${rate+i}` but I've realized that Strings don't work that way in EL. So my most recent attempt has involved setting a variable and trying to work with that. But this is returning nothing as well. I'm really stumped. If anyone could help that would be super appreciated.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${count}" step="1">
    <c:set var="rateName">rate${i}</c:set>
    <tr>
        <td> ${param[rateName]}% </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have used `requestScope` for printing and not `param`, as you are setting the variable in `request`

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${count}" step="1">
    <c:set var="rateName">rate${i}</c:set>
    <tr>
        <td> ${requestScope[rateName]}% </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```